# Receiving error whe run test RuntimeError: IOLoop is already running. What to do?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, pytest

Try to write test for web auth in tornado.
But receiving error:

```
C:\python3\lib\site-packages\tornado\testing.py:402: in fetch
return self.wait()
C:\python3\lib\site-packages\tornado\testing.py:323: in wait
self.io_loop.start()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <tornado.platform.select.SelectIOLoop object at 0x00B73B50>

def start(self):
    if self._running:
```

> ```
>       raise RuntimeError("IOLoop is already running")
> ```
>
> E           RuntimeError: IOLoop is already running

Don't know what to do. Need help.here is code:

```
import pytest
import tornado
from tornado.testing import AsyncTestCase
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tests.commons.testUtils import TestUtils
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler
import urllib.parse
from handlers.authentication.restAuthHandlers import RESTAuthHandler
import app


class TestRESTAuthHandler(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
def get_app(self):
    return app

@tornado.testing.gen_test
def test_http_fetch_login(self):
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(dict(username='user', password='123456'))
    response = self.fetch("http://localhost:8888/web/auth/login", method="POST", body=data)
    self.assertIn('http test', response.body)
```

Comment: removed @tornado.testing.gen_test it worked. Found info here: https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1154

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AsyncHTTPTestCase supports two modes: the traditional/legacy mode using `self.stop` and `self.wait`, and the newer mode using `@gen_test`. Functions designed for one mode won't work in the other; `self.fetch` is designed for the former mode.

You could write this test in two ways. First, with self.fetch, exactly as you've written it, but with the `@gen_test` decorator removed. Second, here's the version with `@gen_test`:

```
@tornado.testing.gen_test
def test_http_fetch_login(self):
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(dict(username='user', password='123456'))
    response = yield self.http_client.fetch("http://localhost:8888/web/auth/login", method="POST", body=data)
    self.assertIn('http test', response.body)
```

The difference is in the use of `yield self.http_client.fetch` instead of `self.fetch`. The `@gen_test` version is mostly more "modern" and lets you write tests the same way you write your application, but it has one big drawback: you can call `self.fetch('/')` and it will automatically fill in the host and port of the server that is started for the test, but in `self.http_client.fetch` you must construct the full url.

Comment: I receive E   ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 10061] Unknown error -  in response line. what to do?

Comment: Is something listening on localhost:8888?